# defaults conflicts on several defs

Tags: elixir

```
  def request(method \\ :get, path) do
  end

  def request(method \\:get, path, params) do
  end
```

On compilation raises

```
def request/3 defaults conflicts with def request/2
```

I don't get why I can't have two argument-pattern-matching def.

Comment: Because if you call it with two arguments, it wouldn't know which one to use. It could be arguments for method and path in the first function or it could be path and params arguments with default method in the second function.

Comment: @JustMichael, oh, I see

Comment: Try putting default param as last one def ss(a, b \\ :c)

Answer (score 3):

Imaging situation when comes `request("post", "test")`. Does the `post` is the name of method or name of the path and same story with `test`- does it the path or your params argument?
I guess the best solution for you is to simply use this `request` method with three parameters and also use `params` as an optional argument.

```
def request(path, method \\ :get, params \\ nil) do
    #logic
end
```

Then you can underneath this function use private functions, where one of them use guard `when is_nil(params)` and one without it.